# Error using Microphone() from speech_recognition module PYTHON

Tags: python, module, speech-recognition, pyaudio, microphone

I was working on a project which uses **Microphone**, so implementing
[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsY9f.png)

I got [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1j1V.png) error.

After finding a little bit about the [method causing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiCZv.png) I find that it's missing a module called '**pyaudio**'.

So, in terminal I tried installing that with '**pip install PyAudio**' but got [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG4vl.png) error.

Also tried installing that in powershell and also in a different IDE, don't know how to resolve it.

Anyone please help, Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pyaudio`?

Comment: Yes it was showing some error, see 4th line

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **pipwin**

```
pip install pipwin 
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Or try importing **wheel** if you haven't yet

```
pip import wheel
```

Comment: Thanks, your first method worked :)